# How can I call a variable from differnent function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

On the first function I tried to return the newFolder so I can use it 
in the second function. but when the second function is called it will keep looping through the whole first function instead of using newFolder variable only. It works fine when using global or defining newPath outside the function. I just want to know If there's a method to manipulate it to work inside the function?

```
import os
import shutil

directory = input("Enter the desired directory: ")

def dir_list():
    os.chdir(directory)
    subFiles = os.listdir()
    return subFiles


def creating_dir():
    newPath = input("Enter Folder name: ")
    newFolder = (directory+'/'+newPath)
    if not os.path.exists(newFolder):
        os.makedirs(newFolder)

    return newFolder


def moving_files():
    for file in dir_list():
        if file.endswith('.gif'):
            shutil.move(file, creating_dir())
        else:
            break



def main():

    dir_list()

    creating_dir()

    moving_files()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest you read about returning values and passing parameters. These are very critical concepts about functions. In particular, you need to learn how to capture the returned result of your function. Every python tutorial about functions will show you how to do this.

Comment: Pass the return values of your function as a parameters to your `moving_files()`, this is the right way to do it

Comment: @IronFist You are missing a step in your suggestion: the OP needs to capture the return value first before passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Correct, but I was *implicitily* meaning that .. :P

Comment: Do you just want one new folder, or do you want to create a separate new folder for each GIF file?

Comment: Thanks guys for replying quickly and helpfully <3

Comment: @PM2Ring just one new folder

Comment: @IronFist With questions from obvious beginners, implicitness is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like the code below.

I've made a few changes to your code. The main change is that I pass `directory` as an argument to each of the functions. I also pass the `newFolder` name to the `move_files` function. It's generally better to pass args into functions rather than reading data from global variables.

```
import os
import shutil

def dir_list(directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    subFiles = os.listdir()
    return subFiles

def get_dir(directory):
    ''' Get folder name in `directory`, and create it if it doesn't exist '''
    newPath = input("Enter destination folder name: ")
    newFolder = os.path.join(directory, newPath)
    if not os.path.exists(newFolder):
        os.makedirs(newFolder)
    return newFolder

def move_files(directory, newFolder):
    ''' Move GIF files to `newFolder` '''
    for file in dir_list(directory):
        if file.endswith('.gif'):
            fullname = os.path.join(directory, file)
            #moves .gif to another folder
            shutil.move(fullname, newFolder)

def main():
    # Base directory
    directory = input("Enter the desired directory: ")
    newFolder = get_dir(directory)
    move_files(directory, newFolder)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that I got rid of the `break` statement. With that `break`, the file moving function would stop as soon as it sees a non-GIF file. In my version, non-GIFs are simply skipped.

Also note that the `os.listdir` function just returns the base file names *not* the full file path. So to get the full file name we must join the file name from the list returned by `os.listdir` to `directory`.

I use `os.path.join` to join the directory name to the base file name, I also use it construct the `newFolder` name. This is safer and more portable than joining by doing, eg

```
directory + '/' + file
```

---

Tested on Python 3.6.0. It will also work on Python 2 if you change the `input` calls to `raw_input`.

Note that the destination folder can be an absolute path, or you can give a path that's relative to the source directory in `directory`.

Comment: same probelm I get when I run your code. missing 1 required positional argument 'directory'

Comment: I thought it was a mistake because there's no function with the name dir_lis() in your code.

Comment: umm...the OP's original post has a `dir_list()` function.